# geom_hline color legend: how do I make it disappear?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I learned from a StackOverflow post how to insert a legend for a horizontal (or vertical) line, which is:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point()+
  geom_hline(aes(lty="foo",yintercept=20),show_guide=TRUE)+
  scale_linetype_manual(name="",values=2)
```

That gives this plot:

[image]

However, when I specify the color of the horizontal, it will also show a separate legend for the color, as if they were different lines. See:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(lty="foo",yintercept=20, color = "red"),show_guide=TRUE)+
  scale_linetype_manual(name="",values=2)
```

[image]

Finally, my question is: How can I make the legend for the color of the geom_hline disappear?

Comment: move `color` outside the `aes`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply following [hrbrmstr's directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332542/geom-hline-color-legend-how-do-i-make-it-disappear#comment54462132_33332542) to get the question closed (code below). [@hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr), feel free to copy/paste my response if you like.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  geom_hline(aes(lty="foo",yintercept=20), color = "red" ,show_guide=TRUE)+
  scale_linetype_manual(name="",values=2)
```